# BSODs sometimes on external card and everytime on integrated

Tags: windows-7, drivers, bsod, nvidia-graphics-card, intel-graphics

the question is:

BSODs sometimes on external card (Nvidia 210) and every time on integrated (HD 4600).

Dual monitors 1920x1080. Core i5 4440, Nvidia 210 DDR2, SSD Kingston, HDD WD, 16Gb DDR3.

Nvidia has bad temp ~80°C idle degree, btw. But PC starts up normally. After some time may happen BSOD, of listed below.

Integrated hangs on Login Screen with BSOD 4f, and HDD led lights permanently.

When I remove driver and use Standard video adapter - with Integrated video PC starts up fine. But after installing any Intel driver for 4600 and reboot - PC hangs on.

Changed memory modules from 4*4 to 8*2 - didn't help.

Upd: forgot Bios version F4 Now - Latest F11, but cannot ask admin to update cause no changelog from F4 to F11 on Gigabyte site. MB GB-H87M-D3H

Intel stable hangs on F4 error:

[image: Intel]

Nvidia:

[image: Nvidia]

upd: here the info from memory dumps http://serjch.com/errors.zip

Comment: Have your Administrator use `windbg` to determine the problem driver.  If you do not have the permissions to update your firmware, Its unlikely, you have the permission to run a program like `windbg`

Comment: I have administration rights, but dunno how to use this tool. I just have no moral & corporate rights to flash BIOS

Comment: Having Administrator rights on the machine, and being an Administrator, are two seperate things.  If you don't know how to use that tool, you shouldn't use that tool, and you really should let your Administrator fix this problem because in the end ALL my suggestions for you will require their assistance.

Comment: @Ramhound I'd got some dumps & debugged em all. [Results here](http://serjch.com/errors.zip)

Comment: @Ramhound, I just wanna know its a HW issue or OS.

Comment: I think problem has solved, in test now. The stumbling block was a "turbo" in memory mode settings in BIOS, I've set it to "normal". Will add answer after testing it some days.

Comment: sadly but not yet.. admin just updated BIOS (at last). will see